# Why does my web scraper skips lines...?

Tags: excel, web-scraping, vba

So, I've built a webscraper (with **LOTS** of help) to pull info from a particular website. For the most part, it works fine. However, it will occasionally skip a row in my spreadsheet. Meaning, it goes to the link in row 10, but then pastes the content it scraped into row 11, skips the row 11 link, and then proceeds as normal from row 12 (these row numbers are just examples; the error is both intermittent and continuous). Also, if I set `IE.Visibile` to *False*, the problem gets worse, occurring more often.

Can anyone help me figure this out, so that the scraper is more consistent...? Here's my code:

```
Private Sub Wait(ByVal nSec As Long)
    nSec = nSec + Timer
    While nSec > Timer
        DoEvents
    Wend
End Sub

Sub Get_Things()
    Dim ie As Object
    Dim retStr As String
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim rRng As Range
    Dim Count As Long
    Dim Status As String
    Dim BadCount As Long


    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Spells")
    BadCount = 0

    LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
        Set rRng = sht.Range("b4904:b" & LastRow)
        Status = "Starting at row "
        For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
            Count = rCell.Row
            Application.StatusBar = BadCount & " dead links so far. " & Status & Count & "of " & LastRow & "."
            Wait 1
            If rCell = "" Then
                With ie
                    .Navigate rCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
                    .Visible = False
                End With
                Do While ie.Busy
                    DoEvents
                Loop
                Wait 1

                On Error GoTo ErrHandler
                rCell.Value = ie.Document.getElementById("content").innerText
                rCell.WrapText = False
                Status = "This row successfully scraped. Moving on to row "
                Application.StatusBar = BadCount & " dead links so far. " & Status & Count + 1 & "of " & LastRow & "."
                Status = "Previous row succeded. Now at row "
    98            Wait 1
            End If
        Next rCell
        If BadCount > 0 Then
            Application.StatusBar = "Macro finshed running with " & BadCount & " errors."
            Else
            Application.StatusBar = "Finished."
        End If
        Exit Sub
    ErrHandler:
        rCell.Value = ""
        Status = "Previous row failed. Moving on to row "
        BadCount = BadCount + 1
        Application.StatusBar = "This row is a dead link. " & BadCount & " dead links so far. Moving on to row " & Count + 1 & "of " & LastRow & "."
        Resume 98
End Sub
```

Comment: ie.Busy can be really unstable from my experience. Meaning it will proceed while the data is not loaded yet. I'm not familiar with using Wait 1. I always thought that it uses milliseconds. Maybe if you try to use `Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))`

Comment: sorry, the `Wait 1` comments hearken to another subroutine. I've added it above. I didn't realise 'ie.Busy' wasn't reliable. I'll try finding something else. But I do need to wait while IE loads the page, and the load time is not fixed...

Comment: Is it always the same cell that is skipped or is it random?

Comment: It _appears_ to be random. I've seen it successfully scrape up to 100 links, and then fail on one, and pick up the next properly, proceed for 20, fail on one, copy the failed one into the next row and the next _and_ the next, then go back to normal for another few, then skip, then double-copy, then skip, etc, etc. It's all over the place.  As mentioned, setting 'ie.Visible = True' helps (a little), but it still happens. It also happens more when I remove the 'Wait' times (which is why they're there), but I feel like that's me hamfisting a patch, not actually **addressing** the problem.

Comment: Also, even when I set the 'Wait' to 3 (which makes each link scrape cycle take 11-13 seconds), it **still** happens. Less often, but...